# Нужно получить 2 точки координат через прямоугольник в mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, карты, map, mapbox

Нужно реализовать функционал поиска 2 точек координат с помощью прорисовки прямоугольника( где соответственно мы можем взять 2 точки координат)
Проблема в том что в mapbox все что я нашел, это возможность прорисовки полигона, тоесть можно нарисовать от 4 точек и больше. Реализация ниже:
Демо функционала: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
displayControlsDefault: false,
controls: {
polygon: true,
trash: true
}
});
map.addControl(draw);

map.on('draw.create', updateArea);
map.on('draw.delete', updateArea);
map.on('draw.update', updateArea);

function updateArea(e) {
var data = draw.getAll();
var answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
if (data.features.length > 0) {
var area = turf.area(data);
// restrict to area to 2 decimal points
var rounded_area = Math.round(area*100)/100;
answer.innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + rounded_area + '</strong></p><p>square meters</p>';
} else {
answer.innerHTML = '';
if (e.type !== 'draw.delete') alert("Use the draw tools to draw a polygon!");
}
}
```

Можно ли ограничить прорисовку до 4 точек, или же задать правило отрисовки только прямоугольника?

Answer (score 0):

Вот собрал пример без расширений, сначала спозиционируйте карту, потом нажмите на кнопку <kbd>mode</kbd> и потом уже рисуйте прямоугольник. Для повтороного рисования еще раз нажмите кнопку <kbd>mode</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 
'pk.eyJ1Ijoib3dlbmxhbWIiLCJhIjoiY2lleWljcnF4MDBiOXQ0bHR0anRvamtucSJ9.t3YnHHqvQZ8Y0MTCNy0NNw';

let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
  center: [30.3, 60],
  zoom: 11
});

let p1, p2, mode;

let data = {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [[]]
  }
};

function toggleMode(){
  (mode = !mode) ? map.dragPan.disable() : map.dragPan.enable(); 
}

map.on('load', function() {
  map.addSource('rect', {type: 'geojson', data});
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "rect",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "rect",
    "paint": {
      "line-color": "red",
      "line-width": 5
    }
  });
})

map.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (!mode) return
    p1 = p2 = e.point;
    drawArea();
});

map.on('mouseup', function(e) {
    p1 && toggleMode();
    p1 = p2 = null;
});

map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
  if (!p1)
    return;
  p2 = e.point;
  drawArea();
});

function drawArea() {
  let lls = [
      map.unproject([p1.x, p1.y]),
      map.unproject([p1.x, p2.y]),
      map.unproject([p2.x, p2.y]),
      map.unproject([p2.x, p1.y]),
      map.unproject([p1.x, p1.y])
  ];
  data.geometry.coordinates[0] = lls.map(ll => [ll.lng, ll.lat]);
  map.getSource('rect').setData(data);
}
```

```css
body, #map {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id='map'></div>
<button onclick="toggleMode()" style="position:absolute">draw</button>
```